# Docker, strange issue with permissions in copied resources

Tags: docker

I've started playing with Docker a few days ago and I've been able to dockerise my first server. But with a couple of quirks. One is related to file permissions in a directory of copied resources. See the following shell session in the container:

```
1dfcc66f2344:/etc/jetty8% pwd
/etc/jetty8
1dfcc66f2344:/etc/jetty8% id
uid=1000(web) gid=111(jetty) groups=111(jetty)
1dfcc66f2344:/etc/jetty8% ls -al
total 68
drwxr-xr-x   5 web  jetty  4096 Nov 30 16:07 .
drwxr-xr-x 119 root root   4096 Nov 30 16:43 ..
drwxrwx---   2 web  jetty  4096 Nov 30 16:07 contexts
-rw-rw----   1 web  jetty  1004 Nov 26 12:35 jetty-contexts.xml
-rw-rw----   1 web  jetty  1452 Nov 26 12:35 jetty-logging.xml
-rw-rw----   1 web  jetty  2277 Nov 26 12:35 jetty-shared-webapps.xml
-rw-rw----   1 web  jetty   169 Nov 26 12:35 jetty.conf
-rw-rw----   1 web  jetty  3637 Nov 26 12:35 jetty.xml
-rw-rw----   1 web  jetty  8507 Nov 26 12:35 start.config
-rw-rw----   1 web  jetty 24426 Nov 26 12:35 webdefault.xml
1dfcc66f2344:/etc/jetty8% cd contexts
contexts: Permission denied.
```

As you can see, `contexts` should be accessible by the user `web` who owns it. But it can't actually access the directory.

That directory is installed with the following section in `Dockerfile`.

```
COPY resources/etc/jetty8 /etc/jetty8/
RUN chown -R web:jetty /etc/jetty8/
```

I'm running it from a Mac OS X host, by means of `boot2docker`.
Thanks.

Comment: This looks like it's a duplicate of this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24288616/permission-denied-on-accessing-host-directory-in-docker

Answer (score 4):

mmm, as this is Boot2Docker, its more likely to be related to limitations in `aufs` - is feels alot like https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/783