# Content of bind mounted folders is unavailable

Tags: docker, bind, mount

I start a docker like this:

```
`docker run --rm \
    -e "http_proxy=${http_proxy}" \
    -e "https_proxy=${https_proxy}" \
    -e "GOPATH=/usr/src/myapp/.go" \
    -v "${PWD}":/usr/src/myapp \
    -v "${PWD}/build/foo/bin":"/foo" \
    -w /usr/src/myapp \
    golang:1.8 /bin/sh -c "ls -l /usr/src/myapp && ls -l /usr/src/myapp/build/foo/bin && cp /usr/src/myapp/build/foo/bin/foo /bin/ && make bin_build"`
```

One of my machines it works okay but when it runs from jenkins, it throws a strange output:

```
`ls: cannot access /usr/src/myapp/bar.go: Permission denied
total 0
-?????????? ? ?   ?     ?            ? bar.go`
```

I suspect that some user access setting messes up the picture but I have not been able to find culprit or the solution yet. If anyone bumped into similar issue before I would appreciate his or her help.

Comment: Is jenkins user part of the docker group

Comment: It took me a while to check it as I had no access to the CLI but it turned out that yes, Jenkins user is member of the docker group.

Comment: Not sure what could wrong here then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the Jenkins server was actually a CentOS where *one does not simply attach a volume to docker*... Using the following command however did the trick:

```
sudo chcon -Rt svirt_sandbox_file_t /host/folder/you/want/to/attach
```

Solution found in the following articles:

- [Permission denied on accessing host directory in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24288616/permission-denied-on-accessing-host-directory-in-docker)
- https://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2015/06/using-volumes-with-docker-can-cause-problems-with-selinux/