# Running 'docker-compose up' throws permission denied when trying official samaple of Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, selinux

I am using Docker 1.13 community edition on a CentOS 7 x64 machine. When I was following a Docker Compose sample from Docker official [tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/), all things were OK until I added these lines to the docker-compose.yml file:

```
volumes:
 - .:/code
```

After adding it, I faced the following error:
can't open file 'app.py': [Errno 13] Permission denied. It seems that the problem is due to a SELinux limit. Using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24288616/permission-denied-on-accessing-host-directory-in-docker) I ran the following command:

```
su -c "setenforce 0"
```

to solve the problem temporarily, but running this command:

```
chcon -Rt svirt_sandbox_file_t /path/to/volume
```

couldn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the correct rule to add to SELinux:

```
# ausearch -c 'python' --raw | audit2allow -M my-python
# semodule -i my-python.pp
```

I found it when I opened the SELinux Alert Browser and clicked on 'Details' button on the row related to this error. The more detailed information from SELinux:

> SELinux is preventing /usr/local/bin/python3.4 from read access on the
>   file app.py.
>
> *****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************
>
> If you believe that python3.4 should be allowed read access on the
>   app.py file by default. Then you should report this as a bug. You can
>   generate a local policy module to allow this access. Do allow this
>   access for now by executing:
>
> `ausearch -c 'python' --raw | audit2allow -M my-python`
>
> `semodule -i my-python.pp`