# permission denied on access /usr/share/nginx/html after volume mount using docker

Tags: docker, nginx, volume, mount

I have used simple command to create nginx container with latest image.

```
docker run -d -p 8080:80 -v ~/myhtmlfoler:/usr/share/nginx/html nginx
```

**Observations:**

1) myhtmlfolder which is my source folder on linux (RHEL ATOMIC) host have index.html. confirmed.

2) when docker exec with cd command to /usr/share/nginx/html (or /bin/bash) i can not ls to this folder and it says permission denied. can not make any file or directory at this location.  sudo not running too inside

3) at host i have root access and folder and file have 777 rights...

continuously getting 403 forbidden

Comment: On your host, have you run docker with sudo or in root mode?

Comment: This may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24288616/permission-denied-on-accessing-host-directory-in-docker