# Receiving an error from a docker-compose that the user must own the data directory

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

Every time I try to build my image, I get the following error:

*The server must be started by the user that owns the data directory.*

The following is my docker file:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: xxxxxxxxxxxx
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: $POSTGRES_DB
      POSTGRES_USER: $POSTGRES_USER
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: $POSTGRES_PASSWORD

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: xxxxxxxxxxxx-nginx
    volumes:
      - ./deployment/nginx:/etc/nginx
    logging:
      driver: none
    depends_on: ["radio"]
    ports:
      - 8080:80
      - 8081:443

  radio:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: "./deployment/Dockerfile"
    image: test-radio
    command: './manage.py runserver 0:3000'
    container_name: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    restart: always
    depends_on: ["db"]
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./api
        target: /app/api
      - type: bind
        source: ./xxxxxx
        target: /app/xxxxx
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: $POSTGRES_DB
      POSTGRES_USER: $POSTGRES_USER
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: $POSTGRES_PASSWORD
      POSTGRES_HOST: $POSTGRES_HOST
      AWS_KEY_ID: $AWS_KEY_ID
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY
      AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME: $AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME

networks:
  default:
```

The image is built with the following run.sh file:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env sh

if [ ! -f .pass ]; then
    openssl rand -base64 32 > .pass
fi

#export POSTGRES_DB="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
#export POSTGRES_USER="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
#export POSTGRES_PASSWORD="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
#export POSTGRES_HOST="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

export POSTGRES_DB="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
export POSTGRES_USER="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
export POSTGRES_PASSWORD="`cat .pass`"
export POSTGRES_HOST="db"

export AWS_KEY_ID="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
export AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME=""

echo "Your psql password is in .pass do not commit this file."
echo "The app will be available on localhost:8080 shortly"

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    docker-compose up
else
    docker-compose up $1
fi
```

I'm wondering if my error is being caused by attempting to use a bash script to deploy the service on a Windows machine?

Comment: who is the owner of the volume files?

Comment: This issue certainly comes from your volume specification `- ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data` which does not rely on a named volume but on a [bind-mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/).

Comment: If you really want to keep your bind-mount as is, you may want to use one of the various solutions @BMitch posted in this very nice answer: [How to have host and container read/write the same files with Docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56060521/9164010)

Comment: @ErikMD I have no particular love of the bind-mount - I received the file from developers and this was how it was setup. I’m somewhat new to Docker, so I’d be willing to switch over to a named volume, which I will lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Details on the issue

The behavior observed by the OP definetely comes from a UID/GID mismatch, given that the specification

```
volumes:
  - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

(which can be viewed as a docker-compose equivalent of `docker run -v "$PWD/postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data" …`) [bind-mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) the `$PWD/postgres-data` folder inside the container, giving access to its files as is (including owner/group metadata).

Also, note that the handling of owner/group metadata between host and containers **only relies on the numeric UID and GID**, not on the owner and group names.

For more information about UIDs and GIDs in a Docker context, see also [that article](https://medium.com/@mccode/understanding-how-uid-and-gid-work-in-docker-containers-c37a01d01cf) on Medium.

## Workarounds if the bind-mount is necessary

For completeness, several possible solutions to workaround the bind-mount UID-mismatch issue (including the most straightforward one that consists in changing the files' UID :) are described in this answer on StackOverflow:
[How to have host and container read/write the same files with Docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56060521/9164010)

## Other Solutions

Following [@ParanoidPenguin's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60531671/receiving-an-error-from-a-docker-compose-that-the-user-must-own-the-data-directo#comment107088760_60531671), you may want to use a named volume, which mainly consists in using:

- the [docker volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume/) command
- and/or the [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) option [`-v …:…`](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).

**Remarks:**

- `docker run -v PATH1:PATH2 …` triggers a bind-mount of `PATH1` (host) to `PATH2` (container) if and only if `PATH1` is absolute (i.e., starts with a `/`) (e.g., `-v "$PWD:$PWD"` is a common idiom)
- `docker run -v NAME:PATH2 …` mounts volume `NAME` to `PATH2` (container) if and only if `NAME` does not contain any `/` (i.e., matches regexp `[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]`).
- even if we don't run `docker volume create foo` beforehand by hand, `docker run -v foo:/data --rm -it debian` will create the named volume `foo` if need be.
- in order to populate the files of a named volume (or respectively, backup them) you can use an ephemeral container of image `debian`, `ubuntu` or so, combining at the same time a bind-mount and a volume mount:

  > Add a file `/home/user/bar.txt` in a new volume `foo`

  ```bash
    file1=/home/user/bar.txt  # initial file
    uid=2000  # target User-ID in the volume
    gid=2000  # target Group-ID in the volume
    docker pull debian
    docker run -v "$file1:$file1:ro" -v foo:/data \
      -e file1="$file1" -e uid="$uid" -e gid="$gid" \
      --rm -it debian bash -exc \
      'cp -v -- "$file1" /data/bar.txt && chown -v $uid:$gid /data/bar.txt'
    docker volume ls
  ```

  > Backup the `foo` volume in a tarball

  ```bash
    date=$(date +'%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')
    back="backup_$date.tar.gz"
    destdir=/home/user/backup
    mkdir -p "$destdir"
    docker run -v foo:/data -v "$destdir:/backup" -e back="$back" \
      --rm -it debian bash -exc 'tar cvzf "/backup/$back" /data'
  ```