# Rails: Bootsnap fails to load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootsnap

When launching a rails 5 application today the following error is being hit:

```
1: from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/iseq.rb:37:in `load_iseq'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/iseq.rb:37:in `fetch': 
Operation not permitted - bs_fetch:atomic_write_cache_file:chmod (Errno::EPERM)
```

Other questions here seem to point to a solution where the gemfile call has `require: false` but that is already specified

```
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false
```

The only way the application server can start (in development mode for the time being) is by commenting out from boot.rb the following line:

```
# require 'bootsnap/setup' # Speed up boot time by caching expensive operations.
```

Between previous re-boot (yesterday) and present moment, neither the boot.rb nor Gemfile was modified. Toggling this line on and off proves the issue is with bootsnap.

What is wrong?  What is going on?

Comment: Same here. Did you manage to get some solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not.  If you find something, please post here.

Comment: I believe [Promise Preston's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61252577/27358) about `tmp` directory permissions is fundamentally correct, but the exact solution may vary according to circumstances.

Answer (score 16):

I experienced this issue when working on a Rails application that has been working fine for sometime.

The problem is that [Bootsnap](https://rubygems.org/gems/bootsnap) gem `tmp` directory in your application directory is not writable to the current user, that is, the current user does not have permission to write to the [Bootsnap](https://rubygems.org/gems/bootsnap) gem `tmp` directory in your application directory.

**Here's how I solved it**:

Simply delete the `tmp` directory in your **application** directory with superuser rights:

```
sudo rm -rf tmp
```

Do not recreate the `tmp` directory again, it's a waste of effort

Simply start your **application** and the `tmp` directory will be created automatically again:

```
rails s
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Comment: Thanks bro...perfect!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using WSL on Win10, few days ago some big update came and nothing worked as usual. As I understand WSL changed some settings for folder permissions, or something.

As my projects are located under `C:\sites` it appears Bootsnap needs to have full rights for `C:\sites\mywebsite\tmp\cache\bootsnap-compile-cache`

Reply in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Shopify/bootsnap/issues/254#issuecomment-477205790) suggests the folder has to be writable. So basically I had to grant full access for my Win10 user to my `C:\sites` and subfolders. In order to to that I followed [this tutorial](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/take-ownership-folder-windows-10-using-file-explorer) If for some reason this doesn't work right away, try to remove "read-only" for your "sites" folder, e.g., [cheeck this suggestion](https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-folder-keeps-reverting-to-read-only-on-windows-10/)

The buttom line is - you have to have full rights for that `cache` folder, so Bootsnap can write in there its folders and files.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this with a Docker container in which the Rails app root directory was a volume mounted from the host. Deleting the `tmp` directory (per [Promise Preston's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61252577/27358)) didn't solve the problem, because then Rails couldn't create it.

Probably [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54787364/27358) (or one like it) would lead to the correct Docker-permissions solution there, but I got fed up and just copied the app directory into the container instead of mounting it.

Comment: I had the same problem inside a Docker container. A simple bundle update bootsnap fixed the problem for me.