# Docker Why are permissions wrong after bind mount?

Tags: docker, permissions, mount

I'm mounting my hosts `/tmp/docker` to `/home/vault/tmp/` in my container but the user `vault` in my container does not have write permissions even though on my host, `/tmp/docker` is set to `777` and the `uid` and `gid` values are set to the same in the host & the container too. How can I fix this and make sure that my user `vault` has write/owner permissions?

**HOST**

```
$ ls -la /tmp/docker/
total 8
drwxrwxrwx  2 ron  ron  4096 Feb  5 19:34 .
drwxrwxrwt 12 root root 4096 Feb 13 09:49 ..
ron@ENGDEV:~/novax-prs/docker$ id -u; id -g
1003
1003
```

**GUEST**

```
$ ls -la /home/vault/tmp/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root  root  4096 Feb 13 06:47 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 vault vault 4096 Feb 13 18:06 ..
vault@novax_prs_build:~$ id -u; id -g
1003
1003
```

**bind mount**

```
docker run -it \
           -e LOCAL_USER_ID=`id -u` \
           --user "$(id -u):$(id -g)" \
           -v ${dir}:/home/vault/ccimx6ulstarter \
           -v /tmp/docker:/home/vault/tmp:Z \
           ${name}
```

funny enough, the `/home/vault/ccimx6ulstarter/` directory has user the permissions set correctly in the container.

Comment: Not long ago I saw this problem and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60129247/docker-file-permissions-with-volume-bind-mount) was the problem. Does it help?

Comment: No, unfortunately just adding `:Z` behind the path does not seem to work for me, I changed the line to `-v /tmp/docker:/home/vault/tmp:Z` but still is owned by `root` inside the container

Comment: maybe you want `--user "$(id -u):$(id -g)"` ?

Comment: I've added that to my `run` command but still no go, I've also updatated the original post on top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

created a `~/tmp_docker/` in the host user's home directory and bind mounted that with `-v`, got the correct permissions in the container and will use this and can use this as `~/tmp/` in my container!

Saying this, I'm not sure why my host's `/tmp/docker/` would not bind with the correct permissions.

Answer (score 2):

Your /tmp folder probably uses tmpfs which behaves differently than for example ext4, especially when it comes to SELinux labeling (with the `:Z` option).

Try using a folder which lies on an ext4 filesystem.