# Permission denied when sharing volume in Docker

Tags: docker, fedora, volume

After facing repeating issues with a permission problem over volume access, I decided to go back from scratch and follow the volume basics.
I follow the following [tutorial](https://blog.container-solutions.com/understanding-volumes-docker).

I then try to run the following commands:

```
docker run -it  -v /home/me/test:/data debian
```

And once inside I run a simple ls /data. But I get a Permission Denied.
If I list permission over data I have the following:

```
drwxrwxrwx.   1 1001 1001  318 Mar 24 19:50 data/
```

Any hint on what I should look at ?

My system is Fedora 33 with Docker 19.03.13

Comment: This seems to be an issue specific to SELinux distributions (which Fedora is). I do not experience any issues running your examples on Ubuntu 20. Perhaps [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24288616/permission-denied-on-accessing-host-directory-in-docker) can help you solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks, it does indeed solve part of my problem, I ll keep digging with this in mind !