# Installing Apex on Docker with the file conn_string.txt created but Docker saying it doesn't exists

Tags: docker, oracle-apex, oracle-ords

I am trying to install Apex on Docker Desktop. Althouhg I am following the oficial guide on https://container-registry.oracle.com/ords/f?p=113:10:::::: , I get errors regarding the conn_string.txt file.

This was the commands I apply following the guide:

```
mkdir ords_secrets ords_config

echo 'CONN_STRING=pdbadmin/##mypass##@localhost:1521/XEPDB1' > ords_secrets/conn_string.txt

docker run  --rm --name ords -v ${PWD}/ords_secrets/:/opt/oracle/variables -p 8181:8181 container-registry.oracle.com/database/ords:latest
```

And then I get the error:

```
INFO : This container will start a service running ORDS 22.4.1 and APEX 22.2.0.
ERROR: CONN_STRING_FILE has not added, create a file with CONN_STRING variable and added as docker volume:
          mkdir volume ; echo 'CONN_STRING=user/password@hostname:port/service_name' > volume/conn_string.txt
```

But if i list the directory ords_secrets, the file is there.

Can anyone help? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check this post [Permission denied on accessing host directory in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24288616/permission-denied-on-accessing-host-directory-in-docker)

Just add :z to mount destinations like this:

```
docker run  --rm --name ords -v ${PWD}/ords_secrets/:/opt/oracle/variables:z -p 8181:8181 container-registry.oracle.com/database/ords:latest
```